# Not getting how to write unit test function of my function

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a function `GetAssemblytree(Assembly assembly)` which takes an assembly and returns all the assemblies referenced by given assembly in recursive manner.

I am not getting how should I write unit test function for this.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Create a dummy assembly that references a couple other assemblies, and reference those for your unit test.

Comment: @user..what is the unit testing framework you are using?

Comment: @Avinash - visual studio unit testing

Comment: You want to control ALL the inputs into your method so you know all the outputs. So mock up your assembly and make sure you get the same value each time through.

Comment: How GetAssemblytree looks like? What is return type? How do you communicate with Assembly?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy it's return type is list of assemblies it references.. What I am not getting is since Assembly is an abstract class and you cannot make it's object directly, you have to depend on Load or GetExecutingAssembly function for this. Making a dummy assembly for a test function , is it right idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# Assembly is an abstract class. You can simply extend it and have a dummy implementation of a concrete dummy class for test, and then everything naturally works.

Comment: seems like a solution but not getting it :(.. say I do like this - class ConcreateAssembly : Assembly{ List<ConcreateAssembly> assemblies=new List<ConcreateAssembly>();} and make object of this class, I still cannot call my function with the object of this class ..

Comment: You surely can do foreach (assembly in assemblies) GetAssemblytree(assembly);

Comment: okie.. May be I am getting it, but how my concreateassembly object can reference other assembly at runtime ?

Comment: You don't have to - in unit test you "pretend" the data you need is referred and return the sample data to the calling function, i.e. GetAssemblyTree() and check if its logic is correct. That's the unit test for your function - otherwise you are doing integration test.

Answer (score 0):

You should not write *a* unit test for it, you should write several, and make each of them as simple as possible.

First, make sure you have a clear idea of what you want your function to do. Make each requirement as clear, simple and atomic as possible. Then define tests for each requirement.

You could define your test a little like this (just a rough sketch):

```
public void Should_return_null_if_assembly_does_not_reference_anything(){ 
    var result = YourFunctionToTest(yourEmptyDummyAssembly);
    ... 
    // Check result in a suitable way
}

public void Should_return_expected_assemblies(){
    var result = YourFunctionToTest(otherDummyAssembly);
    ... 
    // Check result in a suitable way
}

// etc...
```

The main rule of thumb to remember, is to keep things simple, and be really clear about what exactly it is you want to check with each test. Once you are clear on your goals, writing the tests themselves will not be that hard.